# Bootstrap getting started broken index.html

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to css and have bad experience with client side javascript... currently looking at twitter-bootstrap in the hope that a framework will help me understand the complicated responsive css and help me get things up and running quickly with best practices.

However, even the latest bootstrap v.3.0.0 (commit id: 4bac2c567a139958cb2ff35f7ad30c7dcd8527a3 as of now)is not working as expected out of the box. Running the index.html, I'm expecting to see at least well formatted html document, but instead it is a messed up html document

[image: index.html]

I am pretty sure there is something wrong with my setup and I expect to see some well formatted html document like the one shown in http://getbootstrap.com/ but is clueless... Can anyone explain the index.html code means? Particularly  as I'm not sure what javascript framework needs to be included for that to work (I saw similar wierd syntax in Emberjs.com before, but not really sure as the index.html also look like just the content of

Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="bs-masthead">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Bootstrap 3</h1>
    <p class="lead">Sleek, intuitive, and powerful mobile-first front-end framework for faster and easier web development.</p>
    <p>
      <a href="{{ site.download_dist }}" class="btn btn-outline btn-large" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Jumbotron actions', 'Download', 'Download 3.0.0 RC1']);">Download Bootstrap</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you looked at console to verify that all the files referred in index.html are loaded or not?

Answer (score 2):

The index.html file on the root of https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap just contain the "Page Content" part of getbootstrap.com

If you want the whole content of getbootstrap.com you can get it from: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-examples

Answer (score 1):

You need Jekyll to run the local version of the bootstrap documentation.

But an awesome guy helped out by copying the entire documentation and made it available for download here: 
http://web3canvas.com/item/bootstrap-3-docs/

Or you can download Bootstrap v2.3.2 Docs. this works locally without Jekyll

Answer (score 0):

Install Jekyll on your local machine. It is a static site generator used to generate the Twitter Bootstrap site. 
http://jekyllrb.com/